# Initialization of class' static array elements individually

Tags: c++, arrays, static, initialization

I will explain the problem with a simple example.

I hava a class IVTEntry declared in a header file IVTEntry.h

```
class IVTEntry{
    ...
    static IVTEntry* data[256];
}
```

I would like to initialize array entries using the following macro in IVTEntry.cpp file scope

```
#define PEREPAREENTRY(numEntry)\
     IVTEntry* IVTEntry::data[numEntry]=new IVTEntry(numEntry);
```

The goal is to initialize only certain entries in this array.
When trying to utilize this macro I get "mismatch in redeclaration of 'IVTEntry::data' which seems logical enough.

Is there an easy, standard way to solve this, or should I think in different direction?

Comment: Split definition of the array and the initialization into two parts. Do the definition of the array as usual, then do the initialization early on in the `main` function (before the array is used).

Comment: You could also create a class with an overloaded `operator[]` function which initializes each element on demand, and have a static instance of that class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The first one would not fly for my needs, as I have oversimplified the macro (it also declares and implements an interrupt routine which is a function so needs to be outside of main). The other solution seems like it could be implemented but will I be able to call operator[] outside of main?